# Date coming in google Search Result

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

If I publish a article/blog, then If I search the article in google search, is the date coming in google search result  taken from meta tag or anywhere in the body of the HTML or last-modified-by HTTP header or from sitemap.xml

screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You find these types of date indications typically on sites that are highly popular, trendy, and generate a fair amount of content daily though not exclusively. These come from the inception date, the date Google discovers the page. How these can be reliably used by Google is if Google is fetching new content daily. The site has to be highly fresh with new and updated content. You will notice your examples are prime examples of such a site. Others would be MOZ and SearchEngineLand.

Comment: I don't think it comes from inception date, inception date means, when Google discover that page, may be the post is published yesterday but Google discover that page today(SO the today date is the inception date for Google), but they may display the yesterday date from sitemap, or html/schema tag into Google SERP.

Comment: @Goyllo It may have changed in the last couple of years, however, it was always the inception date before.

Comment: @closetnoc: Thanks , as recommended in this answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59559/how-to-tell-how-old-a-page-is/59566#59566?newreg=70fed6d508f14439bb25dd8c7f5b7d37   I have put the date in ISO format after the h1 tag

Comment: @MohamedHussain That answer was written a while ago back when Google was quite limited in how it discovered and used dates. You may also want to add Schema.org mark-up for an article. Google does sometimes use mark-up. Here is the link: https://schema.org/Article As well, consider OpenGraph which is helpful for social media. There is no evidence that I know of where Google uses this OG data, but that could still be an option. Worth doing if you can. Here is a link: http://ogp.me/ Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc: Thanks We already have the OGs for social media, only thing missing is schema config, which also we planned to use. for the time being I just added the date in ISO format after the <h1> and hide that ISO date from the user using CSS(not using display:none). for the OGs you can refer this one also https://github.com/joshbuchea/HEAD